# nodemon app crashed waiting for file changes before starting can you please solve my problem

Tags: node.js

[nodemon] 2.0.16
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `bable-node --experimental-json-modules index.js`
'bable-node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: `bable` vs `babel`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: nodemon app crashed was the terminal output.....how to solve this?